# use Jenkins shell run ''docker exec -i docker-name bash" no response

Tags: python, bash, docker, jenkins

when I run **"docker  exec  -it  docker-name  bash"** on centOS7 service ,it will go into docker container and can run **" python xx.py  config.yaml "** to execute some works .
but if I use Jenkins shell run **"docker  exec  -it  docker-name bash"** ,it will have no response ,I write **"python xx.py  config.yaml "** behind ,Jenkins show **[ python: can't open file 'xxx.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory ]** ,I think this error is not into the docker container ,so can't find the python file that in the docker container .How can I enter the docker container with Jenkins shell .

Comment: There is nothing specific to docker, python or jenkins here. It is a very elementary misunderstanding of how consoles and stdin work (I wanted to say in Unix, but it's everywhere, really).

Comment: It seems unusual for me to want `docker exec` here; it's a very useful debugging tool, but you shouldn't need to "enter the container" any more than you need an interactive shell inside the Jenkins server process.  Can you use [Jenkins's native Docker support](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/) to run an `sh 'python ...'` command using normal pipeline syntax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run `docker exec -it docker-name bash`, you get an interactive shell inside the container that gets connected to your console and the next command you type to the console is executed in that shell.

But Jenkins has no console. It is executing a script, with the standard input connected to a null device (which always returns end of file on read). So in effect it is executing the equivalent of

`docker exec -it docker-name bash </dev/null` (the `/dev/null` is the null device and `<` connects it to standard input of the command). And if you do that on your console, nothing happens and you'll get your original prompt again.

But you don't have to, and shouldn't be, running bash in this case at all. You give `docker exec` the command you want to run in the container and it runs it there. So you just do

`docker exec -i docker-name python xx.py config.yaml`

and that runs the python command, prints any output and when the command ends, disconnects from the container again.

I've omitted the `-t` because that instructs docker to use the terminal (console), but Jenkins does not have any console, just the `-i`, instructing it to connect the stdin, stdout and stderr, is good enough.

Now there is also a way to send the commands on the standard input of the bash similar to what the console would do, but I strongly recommend reading the documentation of bash before attempting that.